# How to find specific row and merge/center cells in excel from powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel document that is created from another deployment tool that reads in array values and creates the excel document. I'm trying to add the ability to loop through column b and find null value and merge cell a thru c.

The logic I would like to use is loop through column B and look for empty cells, get the cell row number and use that to determine where the value i want to merge and center is (i.e. server1 in the picture below). I would then merge and center that row and continue through the loop until I reach the end of the used range.

I have tried using the Range.FindNext(string value) property but was unsuccessful in getting it to work.

Example of current layout is as follows:

[image: ```]

What I am shooting for:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through every row in the used range of the sheet, looking for rows with empty values ("") in Column B, then merging Columns A to C of that row. If you want to run it from PowerShell, you can create a new module in Excel, then open the excel file from PowerShell, run your module from PowerShell, then save. Hope that helps.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Only loop through used rows

    'skip row 1 since it has the headers
    For i = 2 To lastRow 
        If Range("B" & i) = "" Then
            Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Merge
            Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I did a poor job of explaining the process I was using to generate the file.. I have a script that takes info from a pscustomobject then creates the excel file based on that with no user interaction, but I did use your example to form my own solution! Here is what I cam up with.. ```for ($i = 4; $i -lt $LastRow; $i++)
{
    $value = $worksheet.Cells.Item($i, 2).Text
    
    if ($value -eq "")
    {       
        $range = $worksheet.Range("a" + $i + ":f" + $i)
        $range.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        $range.Select()
        $range.MergeCells = $true
    }    
}```